# Custom Error Bars in R - propagating error in gene expression

Tags: r, bar-chart, errorbar

Hi there Stack Overflow,

```
TL;DR: I want to plot a bar plot with bar height 34.30, the upper error
bar extending to 55.68, and the lower error bar extending to 21.12. Can I set 
error bars manually in R?
```

Longer version:

I am doing a delta delta Ct calculation for gene expression data. I want to use a bar plot to show my expression. I also want to propagate error through my calculations. I can do the propagation calcs in R or excel following the methodology of Livak et al. (2001), and get my upper and lower bounds for my confidence intervals. But to plot these in R is troublesome, because I first take an average of each of my treatments, then take the difference between those averages, then transform the difference. Thus, the value I'm plotting doesn't get an input from multiple measurements, but just a single number. So plotting error bars the standard way doesn't work, because there is no Margin of Error for one number.

Doing the calcs myself, I can find the upper and lower bounds of the 95% confidence intervals. I'd like to be able to just specify these as the upper and lower limits of my error bars. Is this possible?

Livak et al. (2001): http://www.gene-quantification.net/livak-2001.pdf

Here's an example of what the data look like:

```
control
sample, gene1, gene2
1     , 30.00, 27.00
2     , 30.50, 27.25
3     , 29.50, 26.50
4     , 30.10, 26.90

treatment
sample, gene1, gene2
5     , 25.00, 27.00
6     , 25.50, 27.15
7     , 24.50, 26.80
8     , 25.10, 27.10
```

So then the averages of each gene in the control are: gene1 = 30.03, gene2 = 26.91

```
The difference of control values is then: 30.03-26.91 = 3.12
```

And then the averages of each gene in the treatment are: gene1 = 25.03, gene2 = 27.01

```
The difference of control values is then: 25.03-27.01 = -1.98
```

and

```
The difference in expression between the control and treatment is: -1.98 - 3.12 = -5.10
```

The expression value I'm plotting (fold change) is: 2^-(5.10) = 34.30
So the bar represents a 34.30 fold change in expression.

I'm using margin of error for my error bars, and I'm getting the upper and lower bounds of (-5.10) and then transforming them in the same fashion (i.e. 2^-X) to find my upper and lower bounds of the transformed data's margin of error. I need to calc the upper and lower bounds before transformation, otherwise I get the wrong upper and lower bounds on my fold change in expression.

```
Margin of Error = (StDev*(T-stat/sqrt(n))) = 0.70, thus

The upper bound of -5.10 is -4.40
The lower bound of -5.10 is -5.80

The transformed gene expression (2^-(-5.1)) is: 34.30

The transformed upper bound is:     55.68
The transformed lower bound is:     21.12
```

So I would want my bar to be 34.30 high, and then the upper error bar to extend to 55.68 and the lower error bar to extend to 21.12.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_errorbar.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9732720/1480928 has the answer for Base Graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, so I'm fairly confident this is possible. I'm assuming that you can get your upper and lower bounds as two vectors of values, call these `upper` and `lower`. First define an error bar function:

```
# Adding error bars to the barplot
error.bar <- function(x, y, upper, lower=upper, length=0.1, ...){

    if(length(x) != length(y) | length(y) !=length(lower) | length(lower) != length(upper))
    stop("vectors must be same length")
    arrows(x,y+upper, x, y-lower, angle=90, code=3, length=length, lwd = 2, ...)

}
```

Then make your plot with whatever values you want.

```
# Plotting the barplot
barx <- barplot(values)
```

Now we can put the error plots on, replacing `y_values`, `lower_values` and `upper_values` with your data or what you calculated.

```
# Adding the bars.
error.bar(barx, y_values, lower_value, upper_value)
```

Comment: Thanks JCollerton, (and thanks to Roman, I should really learn my way around ggplot one of these days). mind if I ask a couple questions?

edit: figuring something out, I think I might've made it work as I've wanted.

Comment: Left my comment too long. K... I have a vector of the my upper values (the lengths I want the bars to be) and a vector of my lower values (ditto).

One thing is that my upper and lower values aren't equal. So the definition "..., upper,  lower=upper, ..." isn't something I want in these error bars. If I want to have the upper and lower bars drawn separately, and receive their values from different vectors, how would I adjust that function?

*currently looking up if(then) function definitions*

Comment: OK, so lower=upper is a default argument for the function. If you don't tell it both a vector of upper and lower bounds, only a vector of upper bounds, it will assume the lower bounds are equal to the upper bounds. However, when you specify a vector of lower bounds this overrides the default argument and you get the effect you want.

Comment: To specify a vector, I would say "..., upper, lower, ..." right? That definition didn't work to change my lower error bars. I think the upper part works, as the upper bars appear to be the right size. The lower bars continue to just mirror the upper bars.

Taking my example of 4 samples per treatment, I have a vector called upper and a vector called lower that look like this:

    upper<- c((55.68-34.30), up2, up3, up4)
    lower<- c((34.30-21.12), low2, low3, low4)

Comment: OK, try removing =upper from lower=upper.

Comment: Indeed. That didn't change the output. I've also just realized that neither my upper or lower bars are meeting their desired heights. Here's the output plot: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v228/markh1822/example%20plot_zpsdjwo9m2t.jpg

I've indicated with dashed lines where the error bars should extend to for that one really tall bar labeled "Dpt."

The value of that really tall bar is 125.1
The upper bar should extend to 166.9
The lower bar should extend to 93.8

My upper vector contains 8 values (for the 8 bars in that graph), and that bar's upper vector value is 166.9-125.1 = 41.8.

Comment: So the values I'm plotting here are:

values<-c(1.0, 0.8, 1.0, 7.9, 1.0, 125.1, 1.0, 38.2)..............................
upper<-c(0.3,  0.2,  4.9,  4.8,  2.2, 41.8, 2.4, 9.0)..........
lower<-c(0.3,  0.2,  0.8,  3.0,  0.7, 31.3, 0.7,  7.3).........

Comment: xD I just figured out what was off.

"# Adding the bars.
error.bar(barx, y_values, lower_value, upper_value)"

Should be:

"# Adding the bars.
error.bar(barx, y_values, upper_value, lower_value)"

Thanks JCollerton! Works like a charm!